# subprogram declarative section order of evaluation Ada

Tags: ada

With the declarative section of subprograms in Ada, is the order in which variable assignments is evaluated the order in which they are declared? For example if I write

```
procedure Foo() is
I: Integer := 4;
J: Integer := I * 2;
begin
--do stuff
end Foo;
```

can I say for certain that `I` will always be evaluated before `J`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like declarative items are indeed evaluated in order, according to [ARM 3.11(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-11.html#p7):

> The elaboration of a declarative_part consists of the elaboration of the declarative_items, if any, in the order in which they are given in the declarative_part.

---

**Edited:** Source of ARM

Comment: A better link is to [ARM 3.11(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-11.html#p7) - AdaHome hasn’t been updated for ages and in an ideal world would have been deleted long ago

Comment: @SimonWright thanks for that, is ada-auth.org generally the most up-to-date source for the ARM?

Comment: It is.  It includes the edition of the standard, which is currently under development.